# connection along a map

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, vector-bundles

I'm interested in connection along a map between manifolds, i.e. the pullback construction.
Let $f: M \rightarrow N$ be a map and $(V,\nabla^V) \rightarrow N$ be a vectorbundle with connection. Then via pullback construction one obtains a connection on $f^*V \rightarrow M$, i.e. a mapping
$\nabla^f: \Gamma(M) \times \Gamma(f^*V) \rightarrow \Gamma(f^*V)$ satisfying the rules one knows of a connection. Furthermore it's caracterized by

$\nabla^f_X(\sigma \circ f)=\nabla^V_{f_*X}\sigma \in \Gamma(f^*V)$

for $X \in \Gamma(TM), \sigma \in \Gamma(V)$

Now my question is how to see the right hand side of the last equation as a section into the pullback bundle. I want to insert a $p \in M$ and get an element in $V_{f(p)}$. But evaluating $\sigma$ at $p$ is both false and doesn't make sense. I could insert $f(p)$ but since this is not a pointwise construction I cannot...
I would be grateful for any comments and hints where to find some references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following may be helpful: given a section $\sigma : N \to V$, there exists a unique section $f^* \sigma : M \to f^* V$, the pullback of $\sigma$. (This should follow fairly straightforwardly from whatever definition of pullback bundle you're using.)

The point then is that the pullback connection $\nabla^f$ that you're trying to define should satisfy
$$
\nabla^f_X (f^* \sigma) = f^* \big( \nabla^V_{f_* X} \sigma\big)
$$
whenever $\sigma : N \to V$ is a section. This is just your equation but written a bit more carefully so that everything really does live in the right spaces.

Comment: ok, this makes a lot more sense. Thanks a lot. Do you have any reference where one could read more about this?

Comment: The standard reference on connections is Kobayashi-Nomizu, Foundations of Differential Geometry, Vol I; it's a bit abstract/general, so good for reference but not necessarily good to just read through. Any Riemannian Geometry book will have some stuff on connections.

Comment: Yes, I know these references but they don't write anything about pullback along maps. Maybe Kobayashi hides something in the formalism of principle fibre bundles which can be translated...

Answer (score 1):

The usual definition for the pullback bundle is $f^{*}V: =\lbrace  (p,v) \in M \,\times V \vert \, \pi(v)=f(p) \rbrace \subset M \times V$ where the $\pi_{f^{*}V}$ is just the projection to the first factor. For $\sigma \in \Gamma(V \stackrel{\pi}{\to} N)$ we define $f^{*}\sigma \in  \Gamma\left( f^{*}V \stackrel{\pi_{f^{*}V}}{\to}  M\right)  $ by $p \mapsto (p, \sigma(f(p)))$. I would write the "naturality condition" for the pullback connection $\nabla^{f}_{X}$, $\nabla^{f}_{X}(f^{*}\sigma)=\nabla_{f_{*}X}\sigma$,  explicitly as $(\nabla^{f}_{X}f^{*}\sigma)(p) = (p,  \nabla_{(f_{*}X)(p)}\sigma)$. Usually the basepoint of the pullback bundle is ignored (as it is sort of irrelevant), so you write $(f^{*}\sigma)(p)=\sigma(f(p))$ and identify $\Gamma(f^{*}V\to M) \equiv \lbrace \xi: M \to V \,\vert\, \xi \, \text{smooth}, \pi \circ \xi = f\rbrace$.

**Remark**. I don't think $f^{*}(\nabla_{f_{*}X}\sigma)$ is really meaningful as $\nabla_{f_{*}X}\sigma$ is already evaluated at $f(p)$ since $f_{*}X$ dictates where you may evaluate it.